# JAVA how can I readl a SQL and add in a object array

Tags: java, sql, arrays, object

I have a problem when I read in a DB. The select query runs ok, but when I try to add in my object array, it fails with a nullpointerexception when the program read . This is my full function code, this funciton is in the same class

```
 Proveedores pro[];
   int num_pro =0;
   try{
       DriverManager.registerDriver(new org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver());
       Connection conexion = DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/fastfood","root", "");
       Statement s = conexion.createStatement();
       ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery ("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM proveedores");

       rs.next();
           num_pro = rs.getInt(1);

       conexion.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   pro = new Proveedores[num_pro];
    try
    {
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver());
        Connection conexion = DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/fastfood","root", "");
        Statement s = conexion.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery ("SELECT * FROM proveedores");
        int i=0;
        while (rs.next()){
            pro[i].setCodigo(rs.getInt(1));
            pro[i].setNombre(rs.getString(2));
            pro[i].setApellidos(rs.getString(3));
            pro[i].setDireccion(rs.getString(4));
            pro[i].setTelefono(rs.getInt(5));
            i++;
        }
        conexion.close();
        return pro;
    }
    catch (SQLException s){
        System.out.println ("Error a la hora de insertar en la BBDD");
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing a call to create each of the pro[i] items.

Add

```
pro[i] = new Proveedores();
```

before

```
pro[i].setCodigo(...)
pro[i].setNombre(...)
```

etc

When you do

```
pro = new Proveedores[num_pro];
```

you are just creating an array that can hold num_pro entries - each entry must be created separately.

Comment: I have edited my first post with a full function code, sorry :-(

Answer (score 0):

Add the following:

```
....
YourObject obj = new YourObject()
pro[i] = obj;

obj.setCodigo(rs.getInt(1));
obj.setNombre(rs.getString(2));
obj.setApellidos(rs.getString(3));
obj.setDireccion(rs.getString(4));
obj.setTelefono(rs.getInt(5));
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Thx to Aidan, I add this line pro[i] = new Proveedores();

```
while (rs.next()){
            pro[i] = new Proveedores();
            pro[i].codigo = rs.getInt(1);
            pro[i].setNombre(rs.getString(2));
            pro[i].setApellidos(rs.getString(3));
            pro[i].setDireccion(rs.getString(4));
            pro[i].setTelefono(rs.getInt(5));
            i++;
        }
```